# Why making changes in a passed by reference list doesn't make changes in the other list

Tags: python, list, pass-by-reference

My teacher told me that `purchase_list=my_list` is passing by reference/address. For example:

```
my_list = ['pen' , 'pencil' , 'cell phone' , 'axiom team' , 'panacloud' ]
purchase_list = my_list
my_list.append('x')
print(my_list)
print(purchase_list)
```

gives the following output

```
['pen', 'pencil', 'cell phone', 'axiom team', 'panacloud', 'x']
['pen', 'pencil', 'cell phone', 'axiom team', 'panacloud', 'x']
```

then why is that when i do the following:

```
my_list = ['pen' , 'pencil' , 'cell phone' , 'axiom team' , 'panacloud' ]
purchase_list = my_list
my_list=["Naufil"]
print(my_list)
print(purchase_list)
```

gives me output:

```
['Naufil']
['pen', 'pencil', 'cell phone', 'axiom team', 'panacloud']
```

and doesn't

```
['Naufil']
['Naufil']
```

Comment: You're redefining what `my_list` is, you're not changing the value of what it was previous assigned to. `append` is an inplace operation.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between names and values. An assignment like `my_list=["Naufil"]` binds a value to a name. `my_list.append('x')` mutates the list that's bound to the name `my_list`. They're two completely different operations.

Comment: @Aran-Fey So when i binded a value to my_list, shouldn't it be passed to the purchased_list too. Because purchased_list knows the address of my_list and no matter what functions I perform on my_list, should also happen with purchased_list?

Comment: No, binding a value to a name doesn't automagically rebind all other names that refer to the same value as well. Can you imagine the chaos? Say you have a variable `x = 0` and you set it to `x = 123`. Would you *really* want *all variables in the entire program* with the value 0 to be set to 123?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Would you really want all variables in the entire program with the value 0 to be set to 123?: Not all variables, but those variables should be changed from 0 to 123 who knows the address of x. Look purchase_list knows the address of my_list variable.

Comment: `x` doesn't have an address. Again, that's the difference between a name and a value. `x` is a name. 0 is the value, and every single 0 in a python program shares the same address. (At least in CPython)

Comment: Python is always pass-by-value, just like Java. There is never any pass-by-reference.